# Link two Google Analytics accounts so purchases are tracked as conversions when users switch sites to checkout

Tags: google-analytics, conversions

I have 2 seperate web applications with 2 seperate Google Analytics accounts.

Users can add items to their shopping basket on one site, and then transfer over to the 2nd site to checkout.

Therefore the first sites conversation rates are always zero, because all purchases are made on the 2nd site.

How can I link these two accounts so that I can track which sessions on the 1st site purchase on the 2nd, and therefore build up a conversation rate?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to link 2 Analytics accounts.

The only two possible connections are with [Adwords](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/1704341?hl=en) and [Webmaster Tools](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1120006?hl=en).

What you can do to solve your problem is to have 2 tracking's in one website, and this way you can have everything within the same account: Documentation here -> https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032400?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this problem would be for your second site to send users back to the first site when they have completed their purchase.   The "thank your for your order" page could reside on your first site.

That way you could have the conversion from your first site be based on the fact that the user came back to the "thank you" page.